# Why do computers keep old cache?

Tags: cache

I cleaned up my computer and found 50GB of old cache on it and it made me wonder, why do computers keep old cache files?

Comment: How much have you [searched](https://www.google.com/search?q=why+do+computers+keep+old+cache+files)? This article, [_Does Deleting the Cache Actually Speed Up Your PC?_](https://www.howtogeek.com/166285/myths-does-deleting-the-cache-actually-speed-up-your-pc/) might be of interest.

Answer (score 1):

The cached data might be needed again in the future and keeping it doesn't cause any particular performance problem, so you may as well keep it until you need the space for something else.

Comment: Why would you need a cache thee is more than a year old?

Comment: Maybe it's an icon from a website you visit every day. But, as I said, there's no significant performance penalty from keeping old cache material if you don't need the space for something else, so why delete it?

Comment: @TheCrazyProfessor There is no significant performance penalty from keeping old cache material even if you will need the space for something else (that is of higher priority), at which time the system will simply reclaim the space. Of course, it could happen for some kind of computers it might be helpful to clear the cached file once for a while when it does affect the general speed of memory operation.